# setTimeout with loop issue with field update

Tags: loops, field, settimeout

I'm trying to loop through a list on a timer (currently 1 second but I want it faster). The problem is that the current value isn't being updated visually & I can't see why.

When I loop through with **Firebug** it **works** as intended but without firebug it's not showing the text change...is it skipping the text update somehow?

I set the timer to 1 second; surely a .html() call wouldn't take longer? Thanks for any info.

My HTML is simply:

```
<div id="winner2"><h1></h1></div>
<div id="button"">
<img id="start" src="start.png" />
<img id="stop" src="stop.png" />
</div>
```

My JS is:

```
var people = ["a", "b", "c"];
        var counter = 1;
        var run;
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#winner2 h1").html("a");
        $("#stop").hide();

        $( "#start" ).click(function() {
            $("#start").hide();
            $("#stop").show();
            run = setTimeout (nameIncrement(),1000);
        });

        $( "#stop" ).click(function() {
            $("#stop").hide();
            $("#start").show();
            clearTimeout(run);
        });

        function nameIncrement() {
            if(counter == people.length) {
                counter=0;
            }       
            $("#winner2 h1").html(people[counter]);
            counter++;
            run = setTimeout (nameIncrement(),1000);
        }       
        });
```

Comment: `setTimeout (nameIncrement(),1000);` – you are _executing_ the function `nameIncrement` right here (and pass only it’s undefined return value to setTimeout). Go inform yourself what’s the difference between a function call and passing a mere function reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `nameIncrement()` and passing its return value to `setTimeout()`, rather than passing `nameIncrement`.

Remove the parentheses:

```
run = setTimeout(nameIncrement, 1000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPGM3/)

Comment: Oh haha; I don't use JS too much so who knows how long that would have taken me to notice. Thanks John

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running a recursive function without defining exit condition. this probably causes overload to the browser which decided not to run the function.

Try:

```
function nameIncrement() {
            if(counter == people.length) {
                counter=0;
                return;
            }       
            $("#winner2 h1").html(people[counter]);
            counter++;
            run = setTimeout (nameIncrement(),1000);
        }       
        });
```

on debug mode, however, the browser is less defensive, so you can see your erors yourself.